# Community Plus Login Users Unable to Access/See Screen Flows?

Tags: community, visual-workflow

Community Plus Login Users are unable to see a screen flow. I get this error:

"Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 321407170-296657 (-429290714)"

Community Plus Users are able to see the flow without any issue. They have the same permissions as well.

Comment: Have you tried setting a debug log on a user and viewing the details?

Comment: I did. There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary with the debug log